# DialogFlow Fulfillment does not reply to Twilio

Tags: node.js, firebase, twilio, dialogflow-es

I'm trying this:

`agent.add(Simple message);`

It works normally with Google Actions
But when the answer must return to Twilio, the error occurs:
`Error: No responses defined for platform: twilio at WebhookClient.send`

What kind of response should I send to Twilio?

Comment: This seems to be an issue with [dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/) not filling messages correctly and throwing that error. There's nothing special within the library to make Twilio responses, so text responses should just work. It might be worth raising an issue with the library itself.